# How do I utilize CustomTemplate property of BaseFieldControl

Tags: visual-studio, rendering-template

Using **Visual Studio**, I am creating custom templates for rendering Content Types in a **SharePoint 2010** environment.

If I want to control which fields, and in which order, I can elect to remove the `<SharePoint:ListFieldIterator runat="server"/>` reference in the template and instead use the various `<SharePoint:[TextField|DateTieField|RadioButtonChoiceField|etc] runat="server" />` controls.

My question is about how to tweak the rendering of the control using the  (and I guess maybe the ) element. Specifically, I want to tweak the way the choice options render. Instead of display in a vertical list, I want to spread them out across a row.

[image]

So...how can I use the following to render what is shown above? Or should I be doing this a different way?

```
<SharePoint:RadioButtonChoiceField ID="Action" runat="server" FieldName="Action">
  <CustomTemplate>
        <!-- what goes here?? -->    
  </CustomTemplate>
```

I tried adding some static text to that area but it does not render.